# How to implement a single capture group for a number that can have 2 possible surrounding characters?

Tags: regex

For example, a string could take on the following 2 forms, where the dollar symbol can come before or after the numerical value:

`I added 5$ to my piggy bank 2 days ago`

`I added $5 to my piggy bank 2 days ago`

This is the regex I implemented to get the dollar value:

`\$(\d+)|(\d+)\$`

But this has 2 capture groups to capture the digits in the string. I would like to be able to reference the numerical value with just a single capture group. Any other way I could implement this regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) are supported, without group (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ya1XzS/1)).

```
(?<=\$)\d+|\d+(?=\$)
```

By only a lookahead, if lookbehind not supported (this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lwbEny/1)).

```
(?=\$\d|\d+\$)\$?(\d+)
```

PCRE eg. PHP even got a [branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) (another [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JrpAM1/1)).

```
(?|\$(\d+)|(\d+)\$)
```

Comment: The lookahead-only solution worked a treat. Thanks!